# How can the momentum of light be a vector in the equation $p=hf/c$?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, momentum, vectors

I have just started with Four Vector

From Einstein's equation for mass-energy equivalence for a photon reduces to $E=pc$ (rest mass $=0$) I can foresee that momentum of light can be a vector (by the help of a little bit of four vectors that I have read.)

But I write it as $E=hf=pc$. Hence $p=hf/c$. Now $h$ and $c$ are universal constants and frequency is a constant as well (at least in one frame of the observer. So what makes $p$ in the above equation a vector? Because the correct answer should come out through every correct way.

So what makes $p$ a vector in the above equation? I have just started with all this so forgive me because I don't know whether it's a very silly question or not.

Comment: The equation involves the absolute value of the vector $\mathbf{p}$. It's as simple as that, really.

Comment: @Javier Sorry  I don't know . But in my book , in proving Compton effect , Artur Bieser uses hf/c* cos(x) and hf/c*sin(x) for momentum Conservation equation along x and y axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special about the connection with the frequency; you should be equally worried about the identification in $E=pc$ of a scalar (energy) with a vector (momentum). The resolution is simply that this equation involves the magnitude of the momentum, $p=\|\mathbf p\|$, since it comes from the Einstein identification
$$
m^2c^4=E^2- \|\mathbf p\|^2c^2.
$$
If you then want to calculate the momentum components for a photon of frequency $f$, you go from the energy $E=hf$ to the momentum magnitude $p=E/c=hf/c$, and from there to the components
$$
\mathbf p
=\begin{pmatrix}p_x\\ p_y\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}p\cos(\theta)\\ p\sin(\theta)\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{hf}{c}\cos(\theta)\\ \frac{hf}{c}\sin(\theta)\end{pmatrix}.
$$